# can I debug restful web service exist in another project netbeans

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I want to debug restful web service exist in another project using netbeans IDE
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

YES it is possible in netbeans using xdebug you need to configure xdebug on remote server and specify ip and port in netbeans for more information visit this link
http://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic29222.html

Answer (score 0):

I know, it's not dirctly related to your question, but with Eclipse you can debug web services out of the box without any additional configuration.